# How to unsubscribe from subscriptions in Find Friends App

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

Recently within Find Friends App I have created a subscription like this:

[image]

And now I would like to remove that subscription because subscribed person is notified every time when I arrive to selected location;)

Where is the place I can preview my subscriptions and If I wish, unsubscribe from it?

Thank you;)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Find my Friends app’s contacts ( these are the people you are sharing your location with right now-as we speak).  Then select the contact you want to stop sharing your location with. Then on top Right there is a “More” option. Select “More “ & select “Stop sharing my Location “. 
You’re all set. Cheers.

Comment: I do not want to stop sharing location;) I just want to unsubscribe from notifications.

Comment: Ops. Sorry. Let me see about that.

Comment: In order to unsubscribe from notifications you must first select the “ notify me”. So don’t select it.  Or you mean that notifications are always on for some contact and you want to dismiss it???

Comment: Uncheck the “repeat every time “. Try that too.